# Incompatible conditional operands

Tags: java, instanceof

The code snippet below makes me puzzled:

```
HashMap<String, String> m  = new HashMap<>();
Map m1 = new HashMap<>();

System.out.println("m instanceof Map: "+(m instanceof Date)); //First
System.out.println("m1 instanceof Map: "+(m1 instanceof Date)); //Second
```

First gives a compilation error while the Second doesn't. Why? Can anyone help me explaining this, pls?

Comment: I could create a `Map` implementation that is a subclass of `Date`.

Comment: Map is an Interface whereas HashMap is a class. So the Compiler can detect at compiletime, that HashMap can never be a Date, but a Map could be a Date (e.g. if you would create a subclass of Date, which implements Map).